# Ignore whitespace while getting word count from a comma separated value

Tags: bash, shell

This is how my string looks like:

```
value="inst1,inst2,inst3"
```

This is how my shell command looks like that will count the number of words separated by comma.

```
echo "$value" | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w
3
```

This works fine as long as there is no space in the value. If I add a space to one of the words in value, count changes.

```
value="inst1,inst2,inst 3"
echo "$value" | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w
4
```

How do I get the output `3` and ignore any white space in the string?

Comment: `echo "$value" | tr ',' '\n' | wc -l`?

Answer (score 4):

You may use this single `awk` command that uses a field separator of comma:

```
value="inst1,inst2,inst 3"
awk -F, '{print NF}' <<< "$value"
```

```
3
```

There is an alternative solution using `grep`:

```
grep -oE '[^,]+' <<< "$value" | wc -l
```

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer. It is basically the only solution here that will also correctly work for `value=""` and `value=,`.

Answer (score 4):

Storing the words in an array and outputting the number of elements:

```
IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$value"; echo "${#arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the space by something else first, then do what you did.  Like this:

```
echo "$value" | tr ' ' '_' | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w
```

Comment: or `echo "$value" | tr ' ,' '_ ' | wc -w`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed 's/ //g'` to remove any spaces in the string. So the full command would be:

```
echo "$value" | sed 's/ //g' | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w
```

Comment: or replace `sed 's/ //g'` with `tr -d ' '`

Answer (score 1):

With bash
Add comma at end of value, remove each non comma and get the lenght.

```
cnt="${value//[^,]/},";echo "${#cnt}"
```